# SharedPreferences always null on Startup - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I've been trying to keep the user logged in if they haven't logged out, just simple `SharedPreferences` stuff, but every time that I save my SP and I hot reload, or hot restart my app, the function returns null, just like it didn't save anything. I've tried literally everything but can't figure it out. This is my code:

**Getting my SPs on startup**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');
  Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), ()=>{print(isLoggedIn)});

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**Saving my SPs after successful user login**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);

  bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn');

  print(isLoggedIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

The writing functions on Shared Preferences are asynchronus sou you need to await them.

Try `await  prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);`